# How to caculate the flux difference and count the number of occurrence in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have data consist of time and flux (4116 rows × 2 columns). I want to find  the distribution of brightness variation by calculating the flux difference between two consecutive points and count the number of occurrence. I tried to normalize the data (mydata_nor) first then I took the difference (d) but I couldn't count the number of occurrence . Also, I'm not sure if this code is right. I'm trying to plot a graph between "flux difference" and "count"  Here are few lines show how mydata looks like:

```
352.3771366  20458.564
352.3975695  20458.295
352.4384352  20454.715
352.4588681  20468.422
352.4793010  20460.531
352.4997339  20465.701
352.5201667  20463.215
352.5405995  20463.814
352.5610325  20463.986
```

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

mydata = pd.read_csv('kplr31.txt')
mydata_nor = (mydata - mydata.mean()) / (mydata.max() - mydata.min())
d = np.diff(mydata_nor)
```

Comment: and what do you mean by the number of occurence?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants to count the number of unique occurrences of differences. Is that it? If that's the case, `np.unique(d, return_counts=True)` will return the a series with the unique values in d (the unique differences) and a series with the number of occurrences of each difference.

Comment: @Ben.T here's what mydata looks like:                                                        352.3771366,2.0458564E+004
352.3975695,2.0458295E+004
352.4384352,2.0454715E+004
352.4588681,2.0468422E+004
352.4793010,2.0460531E+004
352.4997339,2.0465701E+004                                            mydata_nor: I thought I should normalize the data before calculated the flux difference.

Comment: Did you try what I posted above? Also, unless you have a small set of possible 'flux' values, you will have each difference being a unique difference. Do you want to bin the differences, rather than count the unique values?

Comment: yes I tried it .. this is what I got (array([None], dtype=object), array([1], dtype=int64))

Answer (score 0):

I think your `d` miss a parameter `axis=0` otherwise it does not do it along the right axis.

```
d = np.diff(mydata_nor,axis=0)
```

But to do it a bit differently, you can do:

```
mydata_nor = (mydata - mydata.mean()) / (mydata.max() - mydata.min())
# create the column diff_flux with diff()
mydata_nor['diff_flux'] = mydata_nor['flux'].diff()
```

Now to get a DF with diff_flux and the number of occurence:

```
df_output = (mydata_nor.groupby('diff_flux') #groupby diff_flux value
                       .count()  # count the occurence for each diff_flux
                       .rename(columns = {'time':'count'}) #rename time by count
                       .drop('flux',1) #drop the column flux as it's not necessary
                       .reset_index()) # reset_index to have diff_flux as a column
```

with the data you get, it gives:

```
   diff_flux  count
0  -0.575691      1
1  -0.261180      1
2  -0.181367      1
3  -0.019625      1
4   0.012548      1
5   0.043700      1
6   0.377180      1
7   1.000000      1
```